# Get an XML file using Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

When I try to get an XML file (RSS feed) from a site I can't
get it.

The web browsers Internet Explorer and Firefox tell me that I have no authorization.

Now I'm behind a proxy, but maybe it produces that message. Could it be
that from a site (mine) I can't get other resource of another site (domain)
for security reasons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to access an XML file on another domain using XMLHttpRequest then you can't, on purpose... it's a security issue. However, a workaround is to use a proxy page to grab the XML, see these:

http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html

http://ejohn.org/blog/cross-site-xmlhttprequest/

http://ajaxpatterns.org/Cross-Domain_Proxy

Comment: These are valid alternatives to the mod_proxy method described in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The browser is preventing [cross-site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). You have to use a relative path, otherwise most browsers will simply refuse to make an AJAX call.

As one possible workaround, you could set up a very simple [reverse proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) (with [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html) if you are using Apache). This would allow you to use relative paths in your AJAX request, while the HTTP server would be acting as a proxy to any "remote" location.

The fundamental configuration directive to set up a reverse proxy in mod_proxy is the ProxyPass. You would typically use it as follows:

```
ProxyPass   /ajax/stackoverflow/   http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/
```

In this case, the browser would be requesting `/ajax/stackoverflow/tag?tagnames=javascript` but the server would serve this by acting as a proxy to `http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=javascript`.