# Get remote JSON data using local HTML file (using JavaScript - jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, get

I'm just making a small utility with a local HTML file (`checker.htm`) with  JavaScript (using jQuery) on my desktop that requests data from my website every 10 minutes. If it finds it then it does nothing, else it alerts me.

The problem I'm facing is: I can't seem to use either POST or GET from the local HTML file **c:\checker.htm**:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$.post("http://www.mysite.com/st/prod_json.php?products_id=15",{},function(data){alert(data);},"text");
});
</script>
```

I've tried using POST or GET and with the options: "text"/"json" -- all with the same result: Only a blank popup.

My best guess, is this a JavaScript permission issue?

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a relative URL for `$.post()`. Otherwise the browsers will refuse to make the Ajax request in order to prevent cross-site scripting.

There was a related question earlier today: "[Get an XML file using Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243270/ajax-get-an-xml-file/2243310#2243310)", in which the answers describe some possible workarounds.

Comment: The question mentions that the file is local, so it's an origin problem.

Comment: I finally solved it using my local wamp server. I made a local php script that would get the data i need using a cURL and a javascript that called the php script.

Answer (score 0):

[Same Domain Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). One workaround is to write a server side script hosted on the same domain and serving it as a proxy to the distant domain. IMHO, using pure JavaScript, it is impossible to achieve.

Comment: Or you could make it a browser extension - those can declare their own permissions, and don't need much extra code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get data from a different domain you'll need to use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP) to receive it.